# Derivative of matrix with differentiable matrix elements

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I am on some finite dimensional vector space $V$, and I consider smooth maps $t \mapsto f(t)I, t\mapsto x(t)$, where $t \in [0,1]$, $I$ is the identity on $V$, and $x(t) \in V$ are normalized vectors. Based on my reading, it appears to be true that 
$$||\frac{d}{dt}|_{t = t_0}(f(t)I)|| = |f'(t_0)|,$$
and it certainly seems like this would hold as $f(t)I$ is diagonal for all $t$. I assume that this would follow from the fact that
$$\frac{d}{dt}(f(t)I) = f'(t)I.$$
However, this contradicts the product rule, as
$$(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t = t_0}f(t)I)x(t) = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t = t_0}(f(t)x(t)) = f'(t_0)x(t_0) + f(t_0)\frac{dx(t)}{dt}|_{t = t_0}.$$
Where is the error in my thinking?

Comment: How does that contradict the product rule?

Comment: $(\frac{d}{dt}(f(t)I))x(t) = f'(t)x(t)$ but $\frac{d}{dt}(f(t)Ix(t)) = \frac{d}{dt}(f(t)x(t)) = f'(t)x(t) + f(t)x'(t) \not= f'(t)x(t)$.

Comment: On the left-hand side you differentiated $f(t)I$ and then multiplied by $x(t)$.  On the right-hand side you multiplied $f(t)I$ by $x(t)$ and then differentiated.  The order of those operations matters.

Comment: Ah okay I see. I think my error was that I thought of $\frac{d}{dt}$ as a linear operator on $V$, which, if it were true, I think the order of operations would not have mattered. But this is not the case. Thanks for your help.

Comment: $\frac {d}{dt}$ is not an operator on $V$ at all. It operates on functions, not vectors. In fact, you are dealing with differential operators on multiple spaces of functions: In $\frac d{dt}(f(t)I)$, it is a linear operator on the space of differentiable maps $\Bbb R \to \text{Hom}(V)$. But in $\frac d{dt}(f(t)x(t))$ it is a linear operator on the space of differentiable maps $\Bbb R \to V$.